# Visual Studio 2010 Optimization & Tips?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, optimization

I've noticed Visual Studio 2010 is a lot slower than my Visual Studio 2008 IDE, I've found several nice tips and optimization suggestions for VS2008, however I want to know if people have any tips for VS2010

Comment: You really find it slower? My VS2010 feels actually much faster than VS2008 (I have a multi-core machine, maybe that matters)

Comment: It's not specific to a particular version, but if you aren't using Visual Assist-X, you might want to try it. It definitely speeds up a number of things.

Comment: @jdehaan, I have a quad-core system as well with 8gb of ram, it just feels sluggish to me. Mostly when loading projects or files into the IDE.

Comment: @Landmine: I think 2010 is working extra hard to fill up all that RAM with something - you wouldn't want it to go unused, right?

Comment: VS2010 is noticably slower.  They rewrote everything in WPF I've heard / don't know if that is a big factor or not, but I'm with you, not impressed with the snappiness....

Comment: It is (WPF) in some limited cases, but it isn't an overall issue.  Most of VS's slowness issues are related to poor algorithm choices.  Here's an example that [Rico wrote about](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2009/06/05/visual-studio-2010-performance-part-2-text-editor.aspx) awhile back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two parts to the answer:

First, I'd really appreciate if you could [download this diagnostic tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/e8649e35-26b1-4e73-b427-c2886a0705f4) to take traces.  It isn't a fix, but it'll help us improve the product.  If you send me an email (noahric at msft), I can send you instructions and find a place for you to upload these traces.  Same goes for anyone else reading this question/answer; the more traces, the merrier.

Other than that, there are a few things you can try:

1. In Tools->Options->Environment->General, turn off "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance", and turn off the rich client visual experience.
2. You can also try turning *off* hardware graphics acceleration (from the same location).  I've found plenty of cases where the performance is better with software rendering.
3. If you are working with really large solutions, try the [solution load manager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/66350dbe-ed01-4120-bea2-5564eff7b0b2).  It lets you disable auto-loading of projects within a solution.
4. Do you have any extensions installed?  If you do, you can try disabling them.
5. Run fewer instances of VS at once.  I personally run quite a few at a time, but I've heard plenty of reports where people run enough instances of VS to exhaust virtual memory.

Comment: Noah, thank you for your post, I'll try what you said so far and see how it works out, is it's still slow, I'll send you my log.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be a contrarian, but I just turned ON "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" and VS2010 Ultimate is now almost as fast as VS2008.

I previously had that setting clear and had "Use Hardware Graphics Acceleration if available" checked.

I've been seriously contemplating going back to 2008 because of the awful performance of 2010.

I have a Precision Workstation with:

Quad-Core Xeon @ 3.40GHz
16Gig RAM
3x15K 300 Gig SAS drives
NVIDIA Quadro FX 1700
Running Server 2008 Standard SP2

The machine is not underpowered, and if I open a very large solution with VS2008 (it's also installed), with multiple instances of VS2010 open, it opens almost instantly.
I'm starting to think there is an incompatibility issue with the FX 1700 in VS2010.

Maybe this problem is very config. dependent.